# Create StudentSubmission after student has joined class

Tags: google-classroom

The Google Classroom documentation says:

> A StudentSubmission resource is implicitly created for each student when a new question or assignment is created.

When I create an assignment in the class stream, and a student joins the class after this, they see the assginment as 'Not done' in their stream, and the teacher sees an extra 'Not done'. However, it seems the student can not submit the work via the API (because there is no StudentSubmission record when I query the API, cfr. documentation?). Is this expected?

Can I create a StudentSubmission manually after the coursework was posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further looking into this, it seems there was a student submission in the NEW state. I was under the impression that these could not be used for submitting answers, but it seems they can.